# Amazon Web Services Mobile Hub

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, mobile

I am fleshing out a craigslist type app where I would want to connect users based on distance. I want them to be able to have a profile and images on that profile depicting what they want to sell(very rough description). Right now I am trying to tackle the Back end of this. I hope to use Amazon Web Services in order to create a database that can then store the profiles, user info, images, etc. My question is within the AWS mobile hub, between features such as a NoSQL database, user data storage, cloud logic, and app content delivery, which should I include and focus the brunt of my effort on.

Answer (score 0):

So a Quick rundown of services you might need along with their mobile hub names:

- **AWSCognito (User Sign in)** - this will provide authentication workflow/user registration/storing private data like user preferences etc.
- **DynamoDB (NoSQL)** - this will house all data that you want users to share (like products table, users' public profile data etc.)
- **AWSSNS (Push Notification)** - this will allow you to send notifications (push/sms/email) etc.
- **AWSS3 (user data storage)** - this you will need to store files (for example pictures of products). DynamoDB has a hard limit on how much you can store in it per item so its good practice to store images in S3 with their keys stored in Dynamo
- **AWSLambda (cloud logic)** - with lambda you can essentially create a backend for your app. one useful example is, lets say you wanted to send a notification to owner everytime someone shows interest in their listing. You can set up a trigger in lambda that does that by sending out a notification each time a new record in dynamo is created.

I think that should be good to start with. Keep in mind that each of these services come with their own learning curve (some of them steep) so be patient :)